# Cannot tap UIButtons in one view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

In my app I have lots of views and view controllers (around 15). The first view is my "Main Menu" view which has 6 buttons on it. The buttons (Singleplayer, multiplayer, leaderboard, settings, restore purchase, and remove ads), are setup under the UIButton class, linked into my .h file with outlets, and then referenced in my view did load as seen below. The problem is the buttons cannot be tapped 99% of the time (whereas buttons in every other view controller can be tapped).

They worked perfectly fine before I did some rearranging of them into their current configuration (which means resizing, moving, and changing colors in interface builder/code), but now every time I launch the app they either will not take any input at all and refuse to be tapped or can only be tapped in very specific points (when this happens it is true for all of the buttons, but the points change if I leave the view and then come back to it, and the points are different for every button (but typically the top of the button it seems). I am at a complete loss, and as you can tell have done a fair amount of trial and error with this. I have tried clearing constraints and adding suggested, but neither works (I really need there to be none or very few constraints because of my background).

Code (viewDidLoad: in MainMenuViewController.m):

```
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor = [GSTATE backgroundColor];

removeAdBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[GSTATE boldFontName] size:16];
removeAdBtn.layer.cornerRadius = [GSTATE cornerRadius];
removeAdBtn.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
removeAdBtn.backgroundColor = [GSTATE buttonColor];
//[removeAdBtn.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

restoreAdBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[GSTATE boldFontName] size:16];
restoreAdBtn.layer.cornerRadius = [GSTATE cornerRadius];
restoreAdBtn.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
restoreAdBtn.backgroundColor = [GSTATE buttonColor];
[restoreAdBtn.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

_settingsButton.layer.cornerRadius = [GSTATE cornerRadius];
_settingsButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
_settingsButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[GSTATE boldFontName] size:16];
//[_settingsButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

_singlePlayerButton.layer.cornerRadius = [GSTATE cornerRadius];
_singlePlayerButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
_singlePlayerButton.backgroundColor = [GSTATE buttonColor];
_singlePlayerButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[GSTATE boldFontName] size:16];
//[_singlePlayerButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

_multiPlayerButton.layer.cornerRadius = [GSTATE cornerRadius];
_multiPlayerButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
_multiPlayerButton.backgroundColor = [GSTATE buttonColor];
_multiPlayerButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[GSTATE boldFontName] size:16];
//[_multiPlayerButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

leaderboardBtn.layer.cornerRadius = [GSTATE cornerRadius];
leaderboardBtn.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
leaderboardBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[GSTATE boldFontName] size:16];
//[leaderboardBtn.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

Code for the .h:

```
@interface M2MainMenuViewController : UIViewController <GKGameCenterControllerDelegate> {
IBOutlet UIButton *_settingsButton;
IBOutlet UIButton *_singlePlayerButton;
IBOutlet UIButton *_multiPlayerButton;
IBOutlet UILabel *_targetScore;
IBOutlet UIButton *leaderboardBtn;
IBOutlet UIButton *removeAdBtn;
IBOutlet UIButton *restoreAdBtn;

IBOutlet UIView *_background; }
```

Sorry for the long post, just trying to give all the details I can :)

Comment: Check the frame of the container view(s) of the buttons, if the buttons do not fit the frame of their container they would not receive the touch event even if they are visible and not cut off (i.e. superview doesn't cut of subviews). Maybe this is causing your issue.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by the container view of the buttons? As in the view that they are encapsulated in?

Comment: is the buttons superview have userInteractionEnabled?

Comment: Yes it does @AlexReynolds

Comment: may the buttons be covered by some 'clear' view that intercepts touches? You can try calling `[self.view hitTest:_settingsButton.center withEvent:nil]` in `-viewDidAppear:` and see if it returns the `_settingsButton`. If it doesn't, then something is covering the button.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was, and feel quite dumb now. I was overriding viewWillAppear, viewWillDisappear, and viewDidAppear, but failed to `[super]` them, which caused multiple errors in my app. Silly me... Thanks for all of the replies, especially @kambala who helped me figure this out by accident!